# create a random variable in if...else function

Tags: r

```
# rm(list=ls())
Ace <- c(rep("Waterfall", 4))
Two <- c(rep("For You",4))
Three <- c(rep("For Me",4))
Four <- c(rep("On The Floor",4))
Five <- c(rep("For Guys",4))
Six <- c(rep("For Chicks",4))
Seven <- c(rep("Heaven",4))
Eight <- c(rep("Pick A Mate",4))
Nine <- c(rep("Make A Rime",4))
Ten <- c("Cars","Bands","Books","Capital Cities" )
Jack <- c(rep("Make A Rule",4))
Queen <- c(rep("You're The Quizmaster",4))
King <- c(rep("Fill Up The Cup",4))
deck <- c(Ace,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten,Jack,Queen,King)

shuffle <- function(deck) {return(sample(deck,length(deck)))}


readinteger <- function(){
  n<- readline("Continuing?")
}

repeat
{
  response <- as.character(readinteger())
  if(response=="no") 
    {
    print("Game Over");
    break
  } else {
    sample(deck,1,replace=TRUE)
    } 
}
```

We are simulating the card game kingscup and we have a problem with the sample in the else function, because it doesn't give us a random card as we want.

Comment: I have commented out the dangerous `rm`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `sample(deck,1,replace=TRUE)` (now you do not save it in an objekt). Why you set `replace=TRUE` if you want only one random?

Comment: we thought that if we set replace = True then the variable would be replaced.
How do we get only one random?

Comment: If your sample size is 1 replacement is irrelevant.

Comment: Is this card game be properly simulated with `replace =TRUE`? Most card games have a "deal" where replace would not be sensible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a print statement to actually get output:

```
repeat
{
  response <- as.character(readinteger())
  if(response=="no") 
  {
    print("Game Over");
    break
  } else {
    out = sample(deck,1,replace=TRUE)
    print(out)
  } 
}
```

Here you go:

```
Continuing?
[1] "Fill Up The Cup"
Continuing?
[1] "For Chicks"
Continuing?
[1] "Pick A Mate"
Continuing?
[1] "On The Floor"
Continuing?no
[1] "Game Over"
```

Enjoy!